# Change Integer value to Roundoff by the nearest integer

Tags: c#

```
int a =  4;
int b = 3;
int c = a/b;
```

Here the c value as 1.33 . now  i need to change the value as whole number like 2.

If,

```
int a =1;
int b = 2;
int c = a/b means the value is 0.5
```

now i need to change the value as next whole number like 1

Comment: ...Are you *sure* your first example is giving you `1.33` as the result for c?

Comment: @User, weather you want roundoff it to next integer or nearest integer.

Comment: its 1.3333333333333333

Comment: @NayanKatkani next integer

Comment: @User This is not related to this question. This is in relation to the question you posted today. I had corrected your existing script and added in the solution to your question. Not sure why you removed the question. I didn't have time to post the example so I have decided to trace another question you have submitted to get this working demo to you. Would be a shame to see it go to waste after correcting and expanding on it for you.  https://jsfiddle.net/42syj4m8/ **>For>** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107107/enable-button-based-on-checkbox-select-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
int a =  4;
int b = 3;
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(a/b));
```

Comment: @User, if you find it helpful then mark it as answer so it will help others too.